# Excel: Highlight cells based on search bar, but remove highlights when user clicks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with lots of data.
I would like to implement a "search box" at the top, where a user can type in a term/string, click a button, and excel will highlight any cell that contains the string.
However, I also want these cells to "un-highlight" once the user mouse clicks anywhere in the document.

I cannot seem to find the VBA code for this...mainly the last part.

Thanks

I was trying to solve the problem with Conditional Formatting but couldn't make it work, so now I am looking to VBA for the solution. However, I am not familiar with mouseclick properties.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting + VBA to clear

The following formula in the "Use formula to determine which cells to format" will highlight any cells that "contain" the search phrase:

> =NOT(ISERROR(FIND($C$2,B5,1)))

[image]

You can see we use `FIND([the search bar value in $C$2 ], [in dynamic B5 so it applieas separately to each cell in search range],[starting at 1]).
If it finds the value it will not be error, if it doesn't find, it will be error.

If we delete the cell contents, all will be formatted. to fix this we can either amend our formula to include an if statement checking if search bar is empty, or simply add a second conditional formatting:

> =ISBLANK($C$2)

[image]

If you want to make the formatting clear when to click away, then you need to access the VBA worksheet module:
[image]

Next you'll want to paste the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sBar As Range
    Set sBar = Range("C2")
    If Selection.Address <> sBar.Offset(1, 0).Address Then sBar.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Finished Product:
[image]
[image]
[image]